# Using Linked List to print back a given input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the given input using linked list but i am not getting how to read the input and put it back using linked list one integer per line. I have written a code but still getting error.

**Question:**
Given a pointer to the head node of a linked list, print its elements in order, one element per line. If the head pointer is null (indicating the list is empty), don’t print anything.

This is the input:
`5,0,3 3 3 ,34 43 54`

Output:

```
5
0
3
3
3
34
43
54
```

My code

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,data=None,next_In=None):
        self.head=data
        self.next=next_In
    def print_list(head):
        if head is not None :
                print(head)
                print_list(head.next)`
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting and what is your desired output?

Comment: @jonyfries Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 48, in <module>
    print_list(head)
NameError: name 'print_list' is not defined

Comment: @jonyfries  Output : it should be same as input but one integer per line . All the input that i have put in the question is given at once.

Comment: Please add that to your question. Also, what is line 48? Please provide enough information that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @jonyfries i have added the question .

Comment: In order to help we need a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question. So include the code where you are attempting to call print_list and the error you are receiving.

Comment: @jonyfries i am solving this on hacker rank and the first line starts from 40 i don't know why but 48th line is the 8th line in the code that i have submitted . That is all the code that i have actually written.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how you're using this in your code I can't be entirely sure but I believe your issue is that you don't use the `print_list` as a `@staticmethod`. And you when you call `print_list` you need to qualify the method call.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,data=None,next_In=None):
        self.head=data
        self.next=next_In

    @staticmethod
    def print_list(head):
        if head is not None :
            print(head)
            Node.print_list(head.next)
```

Comment: If you are on hacker rank than here is the link :https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list/problem